# Supertest async callback was not invoked

Tags: javascript, jestjs, supertest, resource-router-middleware

I'm getting the following issue by trying to test a minimalist example with `supertest` (and `jest`):

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

Please note that this is not a duplicate of the other issues on SO, as I get the issue even after significantly extending the default timeout value with Jasmine. I'm inclined to believe the issue may be due to the use of `resource-router-middleware` and this post could be useful to others.

My full example is:

**foo.js**

```
import resource from 'resource-router-middleware'

export default () => resource({
  id: 'foo',

  create: [
    (req, res) => {
      res.status(201).json({ 'foo': 'bar' })
    }
  ]
})
```

**foo.test.js**

```
import request from 'supertest'
import foo from 'foo'

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000

test('create should return 201', () => {
  return request(foo).post('/').then(response => {
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201)
  })
})
```

**Full error**

```
FAIL  foo.test.js (61.578s)
  ✕ create should return 201 (60047ms)

  ● create should return 201

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      4 | jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000
      5 |
    > 6 | test('create should return 201', () => {
        | ^
      7 |   return request(foo).post('/').then(response => {
      8 |     expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201)
      9 |   })

      at Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:85:20)
      at Object.test (foo.test.js:6:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like lack of documentation on what [resource-router-middleware](https://github.com/developit/resource-router-middleware) is and how it should be used properly. However, from [source code](https://github.com/developit/resource-router-middleware/blob/master/resource-router-middleware.js) we can see that it's a [router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router). 
So that means we have to specify route path for that.

So, your `foo.js` might do something like:

```
import resource from 'resource-router-middleware'
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const mw =  resource({
  id: 'foo',

  create: [
    (req, res) => {
      res.status(201).json({ 'foo': 'bar' })
    }
  ]
})
// actual bind to our resources to '/' route
// app.post('/', mv) is fine too, but 
// if you describe more than 1 resource, it doesn't have much sense
app.all('/', mw); 
export default app;
```

Or, using [route.route](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route):

```
mw.route('/');
app.use(mw);
```

For sure, there are other ways for route binding, I showed only the first I found. However, the general idea of my answer is that - `resource-router-middleware` have to be bound to an express app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex. As far as I can tell from the short source code it apears that it returns a router? (https://github.com/developit/resource-router-middleware/blob/master/resource-router-middleware.js)

Comment: @Juicy, absolutely correct. Why I didn't have a look to source...? Updated answer, thanks! :)